# Missing intervals in order reports

Tags: magento2, reports

magento 2.1.9

i am currently missing 7 days worth of order reports, we have attempted to use aggrgated data but still no luck. we know we have sales orders on these days

Comment: our customer service team have not been in on the days the orders are missing its almos as if if a norder is not updated its not showing in reports, i have tried to run the reports in order created and order updated still the same